# Main form does not show textboxes and buttons made visible by a procedure called by a second "password" form after close

Tags: c#

I have simple form application (main form called "frmStart"). I created a "Basic Mode" and an "Advanced Mode" of this application.
It's just 2 radio buttons with the look of a normal button "Basic Mode" and "Advanced Mode" in a panel so you can only select the one or the other.
In the Advanced Mode I just show a couple of extra options (textboxes, buttons, editable fiels) that are hidden in the basic mode. So far so good, it's all working as expected.
Now I want to password protect the advanced mode option by just showing a new form with a simple textbox and an OK button to check the password.

The Problem I'm having is when the password form opens and I put in the correct password, I run the same code on my main form to unhide textboxes and so on however they do not appear!
I probably need to redraw my main form or something but I don't know how. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Can someone help me out here?

Here's some code:

A. This is the code that executes when the Advanced Mode button is checked

```
    private void chk_AdvancedMode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chk_AdvancedMode.Checked)
        {
            frmPassword frm_Password = new frmPassword();
            frm_Password.Show();
        }
    }
```

B. This is the code of the password form that checks the password and if correct executes the procedure frm_Start.BasicAdvancedMode(true);

```
    public void btn_PasswordOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmStart frm_Start = new frmStart();
        String s_pw = "ABC123";
        if (txt_Password.Text == s_pw)
        {
            frm_Start.BasicAdvancedMode(true);
            frm_Start.prop_RunningMode = "Running in Advanced Mode";
           // frm_Start.ChangeChecked_Advanced_Basic_Button(true);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password! Try again or use Basic Mode");
          //  frm_Start.ChangeChecked_Advanced_Basic_Button(false);
        }
        this.Close();
       }
```

C. This is the code of procedure BasicAdvancedMode

```
    public void BasicAdvancedMode(Boolean state)
    {
        chk_SYSENG1.Visible = state;
        chk_SYSENG3.Visible = state;
        chk_EditParameters.Visible = state;
        txt_accgcode.Visible = state;
        txt_grpprfowner.Visible = state;
        txt_inlpgm.Visible = state;
        txt_lmtcpb.Visible = state;
        txt_jobd.Visible = state;
        label12.Visible = state;
        label13.Visible = state;
        label14.Visible = state;
        label15.Visible = state;
        label16.Visible = state;
    }
```

Comment: it looks like you are starting a new form (i think) `frmStart frm_Start = new frmStart();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are starting a new form (i think) `frmStart frm_Start = new frmStart();`

You could do this, the premise is you open your password form in `ShowModal();` and check the result when its closed. Add pepper and salt to taste.

**Given**

```
public class frmPassword
{
    Public bool IsValidated { get; set;}

    public void btn_PasswordOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String s_pw = "ABC123";

        if(txt_Password.Text == s_pw)
        {
           IsValidated = true;
           this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Wrong password! Try again or use Basic Mode");
        }

    }
}
```

**Main form**

```
private void chk_AdvancedMode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chk_AdvancedMode.Checked)
    {
        frmPassword frm_Password = new frmPassword();
        frm_Password.ShowModal();
        if(frm_Password.IsValidated)
        {
            BasicAdvancedMode(true);
            prop_RunningMode = "Running in Advanced Mode";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
You are correct that I created a new form object, I thought this was a way to be able to call a procedure on the main form from the second form.
I corrected my code with your suggestions and it's working perfectly now! Thanks!